# protocol type constraint by two protocols

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I've setup two protocols below in swift 2

- Generative (for the lack of a better name) which holds an array of items and provides Datasource like functionality like count and subscript

```
public protocol Generative {
    typealias GeneratedType

    var elements: [GeneratedType] { get }
}

public extension Generative {
    func count() -> Int {
        return elements.count
    }

    subscript(index:Int) -> GeneratedType? {
        if index >= count() {
            return nil
        }
        return elements[index]
    }

}

public protocol Selectable {
    typealias SelectableType: Hashable

    var selectedElements: Set<SelectableType> { get set }

}

extension Selectable {
    public func isSelected(elem: SelectableType) -> Bool {
        return selectedElements.contains(elem)
    }

    public mutating func addSelection(elem: SelectableType) {
        selectedElements.insert(elem)
    }

    public mutating func removeSelection(elem: SelectableType) {
        selectedElements.remove(elem)
    }

    public mutating func clearSelections() {
        selectedElements.removeAll()
    }
}
```

So in case an object implements both Generative and Selectable then I want it to be able to return the selected indices so I wrote this function:

```
func selectedIndices<S: Selectable where S: Generative, S.GeneratedType == S.SelectableType>(ds: S) -> [NSIndexPath] {
    var selections: [NSIndexPath]  {
        return ds.selectedElements
            .map{ (p: S.GeneratedType) -> NSIndexPath? in
                if let idx = ds.elements.indexOf(p) { idx
                    return NSIndexPath(forRow: idx, inSection: 0)
                }
                return nil
            }
            .filter{ $0 != nil }
            .map{ $0! }
    }


    return selections
}
```

for some reason the linker prints out:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Not sure why is that, I can't figure out another way to specify this function to work on objects which implement both protocols and their associated types match...
Any ideas ?

P.S. the code in a Gist: https://gist.github.com/edwardIshaq/715b0e134fb47d2e28cc

------- UPDATE
removing the computed property seemed to do the trick :

```
func selectedIndices<S: Selectable where S: Generative, S.GeneratedType == S.SelectableType>(ds: S) -> [NSIndexPath] {
    return ds.selectedElements
        .flatMap { (p: S.GeneratedType) -> NSIndexPath? in
            if let idx = ds.elements.indexOf(p) { idx
                return NSIndexPath(forRow: idx, inSection: 0)
            }
            return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: That may be a long shot, but try cleaning the project and building again. I've seen this error only once and cmd+shift+k helped.

Comment: p.s. instead of `.map { return an optional }.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }`, you can write `.flatMap { return an optional }`, it will do the same thing.

Comment: @66o I've tried clean and build and all that, Linker keeps crashing...

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Thanks for flatMap :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler should never crash, but it looks like the cause is simpler, seems to be to do with generic functions that use computed properties internally, this is as simple as I can get it:

```
// swiftc crashes when compiling this
func f<T>(t: T) -> Int {
    var v: Int {
        return 0
    }
    return v
}
```

so as a workaround, try refactoring the code to not use the computed property.

You could do that, and write this as an extension of the two protocols, like this:

```
extension Selectable
where Self: Generative, 
      Self.GeneratedType == NSIndexPath, 
      Self.SelectableType == NSIndexPath 
{
    func selectedIndices() -> [NSIndexPath] {
        return self.selectedElements.flatMap {
            self.elements.indexOf($0).map { NSIndexPath(index: $0) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea if its possible to include this function as an extension to either of the protocols ?

Comment: Yup, added a version that does that.